# boost::program_options - Is is possible to enforce mandatory flag?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I'm using boost::program_options in my program. I want to make a certain flag mandatory. Is is possible to do this with program_options in a way that it'll enforce this itself? i.e., throw an error message?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id903171-bb) you can specify that an option is required in the option description:

```
options_description desc;
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help")
    ("count", value<int>()->required(), "number of executions")
    ;
```

Comment: Be warned that there are still many older installations of boost that don't support this. The required() feature was added in 1.42. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2982

Comment: The output doen't really flag that its a required parameter.  How to reflect that?